# Retry for failure endpoint automatically

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-micro-integrator

im working wso2 mi 4.2.0 . in my integration,   we using switch and calling multiple endpoints based on payload.  in that we need to  implement retry mechanism as below in one of the endpoint. its working if cancel the request and trigger manually. for my scenario , it should retry automatically.

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <endpoint name="XXEP" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
       <http method="post" uri-template="XXXXX/XX">
       <timeout>
        <duration>5000</duration>
        <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
    </timeout>
    <suspendOnFailure>
         
        <initialDuration>10000</initialDuration>
        <progressionFactor>2</progressionFactor>
        <maximumDuration>20000</maximumDuration>
    </suspendOnFailure>
    <markForSuspension>
      
        <retriesBeforeSuspension>3</retriesBeforeSuspension>
        <retryDelay>1</retryDelay>
    </markForSuspension>
   
</http>
```

Requesting suggestion